# Prove that if ($a_n$) converges to $L$, then ($a_n^2$) converges to $L^2$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

My question read to prove that if ($a_n$) converges to $L$, then ($a_n^2$) converges to $L^2$.

Thus I have that given $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that |$a_n-L|<\epsilon$.

Now, I see I need |$a_n^2-L|<\epsilon$, which I am seeing is equal to |($a_n-L)(a_n+L)$|. I was going to try to use triangle inequality, but I do not think this would be best in this case. I just know I need to divide $\epsilon$ by something to get that when I multiply these two, I will get $\epsilon$.

How can I determine what to make $\epsilon$ be?

Comment: Hint: you need an upper bound on $|a_n + L|$. How should you go about doing this?

Comment: It is also true that $|L - a_n| < \epsilon!$

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 since ($a_n$) converges it is bounded so |$a_n|\leq\ M$ for $M>0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**:

$1)$ $a_n$ is bounded, thus $|a_n| \le M, \forall n \ge 1$

$2)$ $|a_n+L| \le |a_n|+|L| \le M+|L|$

$3)$ $|a_n^2-L^2| = |a_n - L||a_n +L|$

Comment: Yes, I get to this part, but I am not too sure how to continue. I have instead |$a_n$ $^2$ -$a_nL+a_nL-L^2$| then I split this up and now I have |$a_n$||$a_n-L$|+|L||$a_n-L$|

Answer (score 0):

$$
|(a_n-L)(a_n+L)|\le |a_n-L|(|a_n-L|+2|L|).
$$